# Construct mysql DB for school diary

Tags: mysql, structure

I wonder how to construct mysql DB for school diary.
It will contain info for the students of some class,assessments on their school subjects(math,english and etc.) and school notes.
But for class of 30 students I can't figure out the best solution for constructing the DB.
Can you give me some advices?

Comment: Can you include more information about the information you want to store? You said it's a diary....does each student have one? Can students have more than one diary? Is the information in each diary unique? Providing more detail about your requirements can help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

1. Read about [ER (Entity Relationships' models)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model).
2. Think how you would organize your data.
3. Read about foreign keys.
4. Apply acquired knowledge to design the database.
5. Implement database design in MySQL RDBMS.

If you wish, there are already some tools that will help you in creating database structure, such as Enterprise Architect (paid one) or MySQL Workbench (it is free, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

you need an admin tool like phpMyAdmin or the MySQL tool that is available at the MySQL.com site (see downloads).  i can't recommend any books for learning database design and it's not a trivial matter that can be condensed into a few paragraphs.  you might take a look at this ... http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html

good luck

Comment: I have some experience in development and DB normalization but specificly for school diary I can't figure out something.It's hard or too easy.

Comment: what are you stumbling over?  is 'school diary' a software package?